# Rebus priority on message

Tags: rebus

Is it possible using Rebus to set priority on messages?

The scenario is that we have a queueworker singing documents, for different services, some of them witch the user awaits the result, and some that the signed document is just stored for later use.

It would then be nice to prioritize the messages of the users that awaits a response. Is this possible ?

We are using Rebus2 with Azure ServiceBus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, since Azure Service Bus does not natively support message prioritization, and implementing it with the [priority queue pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589794.aspx) would be cumbersome, it cannot readily be done by setting a priority on a message.

A simple approach that works in the general case is to have separate Rebus instances for different priorities, where one particular instance could then be used to "fast-track" messages that need to overtake all the other messages.

The instances could have the exact same configuration, except they use different input queues. This way, the routing configuration (endpoint mappings) get to determine which priority a message gets.

Comment: Would you differentiate the queues with the number of workers (and different input queues obviously) or would you recommend another approach ?

Comment: Most importantly, you would have one endpoint for not-to-time-critical things, which would be doing the bulk of the work in the background, and then you would have the endpoint that would function as a message fast-track. But yes, if resources are scarce, it would probably make lots of sense to e.g. configure fewer worker threads in the background worker for the less time-critical work.